# how to define 1 ccs cm as a real cm

Tags: javascript, java, cordova, scaling

I'm in the process of making an app that should work on 2 android devices, the Samsung galaxy tab s2 and a RuggedT T5 tabled.

I'm using cordova, which in turn uses html and css.
What i'm struggling with is that 1 px on one device is not the same on the other device, this is a known problem, and no one have an answer for this.

I'm in the fortunate situation that i only has to support known devices and can therefore make static changes and doesn't have to make a general case.

I have tried solving this in pure css

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1000px){
    html{
        transform: scale(0.9,0.9);
        margin-top: -32px;
        margin-bottom: -32px;
        margin-left: -54px;
        margin-right: -53px;
    }
}
```

This worked very well, except when i'm working with OpenLayers for map support. Here i was using the map.forEachFeatureAtPixel with a hitTolerance that didn't support this form of scaling.

```
map.forEachFeatureAtPixel( evt.pixel, featureCallback , {hitTolerance:25} );
```

One of my ideas was to detect what device the app was running on and then scale the webview, but i was not able to find a way to do this.

Anyone that has some great ideas on how to solve this. Any form of solution is welcome, (java,javascript,css,...)

Answer (score 0):

After some research i found out that CSS now has variables.
what i then did was to multiply a scale to all important values.

This is off cause not an ideal solution, but it works.

in the top if my CSS i had to define the scale.

```
:root {
    --device-scale: 1.0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:1000px){
    :root {
        --device-scale: 0.9;
    }
}
```

And in the rest i had to multiply.

```
#map{
    position: absolute;
    top: calc( 55px* var(--device-scale) );
    bottom: calc( 115px * var(--device-scale) );
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
```